# Content not displayed despite present data - React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Could you tell me why my offer content is always empty ?

The "toto" is not displayed and my data are displayed because of the line "console.log(offers").
[image]

```js
const ListProduct = (offers : any) => {

    console.log(offers);

     const offersDisplay = offers ? (
         <div>
             { () => {
                    console.log("test");
                    offers.map((shop :any) => {
                        shop.offers.map((offer:any) => {
                            return(
                                <div className="card border-secondary mb-3 listMaxWidth">
                                    <div className="card-header">{shop.name}</div>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <img src={offer.picture} className="imgOffer"/>
                                        <h4 className="card-title">{offer.name}</h4>
                                        <p className="card-text">{shop.description}</p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            );
                        });
                    })
                }
            }
        </div>
     ):'toto';
        
    return(
        <div>
            {offersDisplay }
         </div>
    )
}
export default ListProduct;
```

I tried so many different way to write it, unfortunately can't find the right way ...

Could you help me please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, with the `() => { /* ... */ }` function, do you ever call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass a callback function in your code

```
 const offersDisplay = offers ? (
     <div>
           //this callback
         { () => {
```

And also you don't return from your first map.

And the last thing is that you need to include the code in your return that way it gets executed every time the `offers` data is changed.

You need to change your code like this

```
const ListProduct = (offers : any) => {
    return(
        <div>
            {
                offers && offers.length && offers.map((shop :any) => {
                    return shop.offers.map((offer:any) => {
                        return(
                            <div className="card border-secondary mb-3 listMaxWidth">
                                <div className="card-header">{shop.name}</div>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                    <img src={offer.picture} className="imgOffer"/>
                                    <h4 className="card-title">{offer.name}</h4>
                                    <p className="card-text">{shop.description}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    });
                })
            }  
        </div>
    )
}

export default ListProduct;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem is that when I try this solution an "TypeError: offers.map is not a function" appears, I don't understand why because offers is an array. Do you know why ?

Comment: It may be because offers is not yet defined at the first time react tries to render the component, you need to add a check before you start to map like this `offers && offers.length && offers.map...` see my updated answer.

Comment: I am so sorry to bother you, I don't have the error anymore. But my content is still empty :/ The code doesn't pass the condition "offers && offers.length"...

Comment: The reason is because as I mentioned above `offers` is not defined at the time your code runs the first time and the function is only run once when the page loads, see my updated answer to fix it.

Comment: Just updated my answer, let me know if that helps.

Comment: It's still empty :/

Comment: Thank you for your big help, It was because of the props declarations. I should write this: ````
interface Props {
    shops: any

}
const ListProduct = ({shops} : Props) => { ````